# Exit a process using an event (Windows, c#)

Tags: c#, windows, process, ipc

Consider a case where there are two processes. Process 1 sends a request to Process 2 to exit itself using IPC (e.g. WCF).

Process2 cannot simply have an exit method:

```
void exit()
{
   System...Exit(0);
}
```

as the method call from Process1 would just die. How can I make sure that Process2 exits gracefully (on a different thread maybe)?

I have researched a considerable bit but I don't have anything concrete.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would do what you're thinking.

```
void scheduleShutdown() {
  System.Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem ( ()=>{ Sleep(30s); System.Exit(); } ); 
}
```

It's a horrifically ugly solution, as any threads that are running will be killed. Ideally each thread of yours would be checking for the shutdown signal and exiting gracefully.